# Linq query in EF Core 2 when using joins and pagination order by column alias doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

We are currently trying to write out sorting into our server-side pagination using `Linq` and `EF Core 2`. We are running into an issue where the column alias being produced by `Linq` does not work while using pagination. However if we do not paginate it works as intended.

All of the columns within the outputted queries are aliases as we have different property names in the model and database column names are different, but this shouldn't make a difference to our knowledge.

This is the `Linq` query without the pagination:

```
var source = from p in _ppmRepository.GetAll()
                         join jt in _jobTypeRepository.GetAll() on p.PpmFkeyInSeq equals jt.Id into jtdata
                         from jt in jtdata.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join a in _assetRepository.GetAll() on p.PpmFkeyArSeq equals a.Id into aData
                         from a in aData.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where p.PpmFkeyBgSeq == bldId
                         orderby p.PpmFreq
                         select new BuildingPpmListViewModel
                         {
                             PpmId = p.Id,
                             PpmFreq = p.PpmFreq,
                             PpmNextService = p.PpmNextService,
                             TotalCost = p.TotalCost,
                             PpmPeriodUnits = p.PpmPeriodUnits,
                             PpmFkeyPriDesc = p.PpmFkeyPriDesc,
                             JtTitle = jt.JtTitle,
                             AssetId = p.PpmFkeyArSeq,
                             AssetDescription = a.AssetDescription,
                             IsDeleted = p.IsDeleted

                         };
            source = source.Where(i => i.JtTitle.Contains("audit") && i.AssetDescription.Contains("df"));
```

This is the outputted query produced by ef core which works:

```
SELECT [p].[PPM_SEQ] AS [PpmId], [p].[PPM_FREQ] AS [PpmFreq], [p].[PPM_NEXT_SERVICE] AS [PpmNextService], 
CAST([p].[TotalCost] AS float) AS [TotalCost], [p].[PPM_PERIOD_UNITS] AS [PpmPeriodUnits], [p].[PPM_FKEY_PRI_DESC] AS [PpmFkeyPriDesc], 
[t].[jt_title] AS [JtTitle], [p].[PPM_FKEY_AR_SEQ] AS [AssetId], [t0].[AR_DESCRIPTION] AS [AssetDescription], [p].[Deleted] AS [IsDeleted]
FROM [PPMs] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [j].*
    FROM [JobTypes] AS [j]
) AS [t] ON [p].[PPM_FKEY_IN_SEQ] = [t].[jt_seq]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [a].*
    FROM [Assets] AS [a]
) AS [t0] ON [p].[PPM_FKEY_AR_SEQ] = [t0].[ar_seq]
WHERE ([p].[PPM_FKEY_BG_SEQ] = 172) AND ((CHARINDEX(N'audit', [t].[jt_title]) > 0) AND (CHARINDEX(N'df', [t0].[AR_DESCRIPTION]) > 0))
ORDER BY [PpmFreq]
```

This is the `Linq` query with the pagination:

```
var source = from p in _ppmRepository.GetAll()

                         join jt in _jobTypeRepository.GetAll() on p.PpmFkeyInSeq equals jt.Id into jtdata
                         from jt in jtdata.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join a in _assetRepository.GetAll() on p.PpmFkeyArSeq equals a.Id into aData
                         from a in aData.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         where p.PpmFkeyBgSeq == bldId
                         orderby p.PpmFreq
                         select new BuildingPpmListViewModel
                         {
                             PpmId = p.Id,
                             PpmFreq = p.PpmFreq,
                             PpmNextService = p.PpmNextService,
                             TotalCost = p.TotalCost,
                             PpmPeriodUnits = p.PpmPeriodUnits,
                             PpmFkeyPriDesc = p.PpmFkeyPriDesc,
                             JtTitle = jt.JtTitle,
                             AssetId = p.PpmFkeyArSeq,
                             AssetDescription = a.AssetDescription,
                             IsDeleted = p.IsDeleted

                         };
            source = source.Where(i => i.JtTitle.Contains("audit") && i.AssetDescription.Contains("df")).Skip(0).Take(50);
```

This is the output of the pagination where in the over function order by PpmFreq is the alias of `[p].[PPM_FREQ]` that SQL can not find:

```
SELECT [t1].[PpmId], [t1].[PpmFreq], [t1].[PpmNextService], [t1].[TotalCost], [t1].[PpmPeriodUnits], 
[t1].[PpmFkeyPriDesc], [t1].[JtTitle], [t1].[AssetId], [t1].[AssetDescription], [t1].[IsDeleted]
FROM (
    SELECT [p].[PPM_SEQ] AS [PpmId], [p].[PPM_FREQ] AS [PpmFreq], [p].[PPM_NEXT_SERVICE] AS [PpmNextService], 
    CAST([p].[TotalCost] AS float) AS [TotalCost], [p].[PPM_PERIOD_UNITS] AS [PpmPeriodUnits], [p].[PPM_FKEY_PRI_DESC] AS 
    [PpmFkeyPriDesc], [t].[jt_title] AS [JtTitle], [p].[PPM_FKEY_AR_SEQ] AS [AssetId], [t0].[AR_DESCRIPTION] AS [AssetDescription], 
    [p].[Deleted] AS [IsDeleted], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [PpmFreq]) AS [__RowNumber__]
    FROM [PPMs] AS [p]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [j].*
        FROM [JobTypes] AS [j]
    ) AS [t] ON [p].[PPM_FKEY_IN_SEQ] = [t].[jt_seq]
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT [a].*
        FROM [Assets] AS [a]
    ) AS [t0] ON [p].[PPM_FKEY_AR_SEQ] = [t0].[ar_seq]
    WHERE (([p].[PPM_FKEY_BG_SEQ] = 172)) AND ((CHARINDEX(N'audit', [t].[jt_title]) > 0) 
    AND (CHARINDEX(N'df', [t0].[AR_DESCRIPTION]) > 0))
) AS [t1]
WHERE ([t1].[__RowNumber__] > 0) AND ([t1].[__RowNumber__] <= (50))
```

This looks to be where our issues are coming from as we can slightly modify it to get a correct result from the database:

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [PpmFreq]) AS [__RowNumber__]`

If we were to modify the above statement to also include the table alias as `[p].[PPM_FREQ]`, like so: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [p].[PPM_FREQ]) AS [__RowNumber__]` then our issues are resolved, but that doesnt seem possible with our current linq query.

Comment: Try running query in SQL Server Management Studio )SSMS) and see what errors you get.  The error message are much better in SSMS than in c#.

Comment: @jdweng sadly there both the same in terms of error, Were still unsure as to why the generated query does not contain a reference to our alias. Thus it will always return the same error.

Comment: This is a known issue which has been fixed for upcoming release of 2.1 You can see more details and possible work-around here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue of that we have later filed with the ef core team directly.

> This is a known issue which has been fixed for upcoming release of 2.1
>   You can see more details and possible work-around here
>   github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9535`
>   Smit Patel

If you run a nightly build you can fix the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

See if following works better :

```
            var source = (from p in _ppmRepository.GetAll()
                         join jt in _jobTypeRepository.GetAll() on p.PpmFkeyInSeq equals jt.Id into jtdata
                         from jt in jtdata.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         join a in _assetRepository.GetAll() on p.PpmFkeyArSeq equals a.Id into aData
                         from a in aData.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select new BuildingPpmListViewModel
                         {
                             PpmId = p.Id,
                             PpBgSeq = p.PpmFkeyBgSeq,
                             PpmFreq = p.PpmFreq,
                             PpmNextService = p.PpmNextService,
                             TotalCost = p.TotalCost,
                             PpmPeriodUnits = p.PpmPeriodUnits,
                             PpmFkeyPriDesc = p.PpmFkeyPriDesc,
                             JtTitle = jt.JtTitle,
                             AssetId = p.PpmFkeyArSeq,
                             AssetDescription = a.AssetDescription,
                             IsDeleted = p.IsDeleted

                         })
                         .Where(x =>  x.PpBgSeq == bldId)
                         .OrderBy(x => x.PpmFreq)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns back the exact same effect as the above query, thanks for the answer though.